# How to make the key of a dictionary as the index of a mergerd dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dict` named `percent_dict` that has 17 `dfs` in it.

Sample `dfs`:

`Hffpw`

```
          key                percentage
0   step19_without_lof  14.534883720930232
```

`Hflpw`

```
           key                percentage
0   step19_without_lof  14.970930232558139
```

`Bgf`

```
             key             percentage
0   step1_without_lof   1.5988372093023255
1   step2_without_lof   30.377906976744185
2   step5_without_lof   3.197674418604651
3   step7_without_lof   9.738372093023257
4   step12_without_lof  5.377906976744186
5   step15_without_lof  4.215116279069767
6   step16_without_lof  6.8313953488372094
7   step19_without_lof  13.80813953488372
8   step24_without_lof  9.883720930232558
9   step25_without_lof  11.337209302325581
10  step26_without_lof  9.738372093023257
11  step27_without_lof  9.738372093023257
```

and so on.

I have pivoted them as follows:

```
def pivoting(df):
    d = pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'percentage', columns = ['key'])
    return d

pivoting('Hffpw')
pivoting('Hflpw')
pivoting('Bgf')
```

The dict of `dfs` after pivoting looks as follows:

[image]

I am trying to merge all these dataframes (values in the `percent_dict`) and the Keys must be the index of the resulting dataframes.

I did as follows:

```
a = pd.concat(percent_dict.values())
```

and it gives me:

[image]

In the pic, we can see that `percentage` is the index. But I would like to know how to assign the `Keys` from the `percent_dict` as the index of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is first [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), then convert `MultiIndex` to columns and last use `pivot_table`:

```
df = (pd.concat(percent_dict)
        .reset_index()
        .pivot_table(index='level_0', values = 'percentage', columns = 'key'))

print (df)
key      step12_without_lof  step15_without_lof  step16_without_lof  \
level_0                                                               
Bgf                5.377907            4.215116            6.831395   
Hffpw                   NaN                 NaN                 NaN   
Hflpw                   NaN                 NaN                 NaN   

key      step19_without_lof  step1_without_lof  step24_without_lof  \
level_0                                                              
Bgf               13.808140           1.598837            9.883721   
Hffpw             14.534884                NaN                 NaN   
Hflpw             14.970930                NaN                 NaN   

key      step25_without_lof  step26_without_lof  step27_without_lof  \
level_0                                                               
Bgf               11.337209            9.738372            9.738372   
Hffpw                   NaN                 NaN                 NaN   
Hflpw                   NaN                 NaN                 NaN   

key      step2_without_lof  step5_without_lof  step7_without_lof  
level_0                                                           
Bgf              30.377907           3.197674           9.738372  
Hffpw                  NaN                NaN                NaN  
Hflpw                  NaN                NaN                NaN
```